# How to create a loop that: sums an error term for 4 months, and divide with the sum of the equivalent 4 months' true numbers, in r?

Tags: r, loops, rolling-computation

I’m working on a forecasting problem, where the goal is to predict number of items a company should buy for inventory for the next 9 months. My data is monthly, but I’m asked to create an “moving/rolling error rate” over a 4-month period. I have tried with: ma(me/outsamp*100, order = 4 , centre =FALSE). However I realized that, averaging the percentage error for the 4 months, isn’t equal to: the sum of a 4 month forecast /  the sum of the given 4 month period * 100 ((prediction_1+p_2+p_3+p_4)/(actual no. of sold items_1 +a_2+a_3+a_4) * 100.) The test set consists of the first 9 months of 2021. So, I would like to create a solution where the Error is calculated for month 1+2+3+4 and secondly for 2+3+4+5 and forward until 6+7+8+9 (perhaps a for loop).

Sample data, (and the error (4) is calculated in excel, and then imported to r, in order to upload it here. )

```
df<-data.frame(predictions = c(393.4, 511.4, 471.7, 679.2, 613.9, 
                           456.2, 603.2, 668.2, 512.4), 
           outsamp = c(662, 416, 594, 495, 442, 480, 263, 464, 507),
           ME = c(268.6, -95.4, 122.3, -184.2, -171.9, 23.8, -340.2, -204.2, -5.4),
           `error (4)` = c(NA, 0.0513613290263037, -0.169080636877247, -0.104425658876181, 0.400297619047619, -0.419951485748939, 
                          -0.306884480746791, NA, NA),
           `error (5)` = c(NA, NA, -0.0232272901494825,-0.125834363411619, -0.241952506596306, -0.408908582089552, -0.323701298701299, NA, NA), 
           `error (6)` = c(NA, NA, -0.0119132405309161, -0.24,-0.275529583637692, -0.332742361373067, NA, NA, NA))
```

calculations in excel are shown underneath[excel calculations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/al2iN.png)

Comment: It's possible to share your data! Use `dput(df)`, assuming your data is called `df`, and post the results in a code chunk in your question! This makes it much easier to help you.

Comment: I just edited my question, did I use dput right?

Comment: I later found the function 'rollsum', which turned out to be useful, except it should stop when the window no longer is complete with 4 observations. The following does solwe the issue partly: `ma_me_4<-rollsum(df.error2.2$me,k =4) / rollsum(df.error2.2$outsamp,k =4) * 100`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can calculate rolling sums with a loop using row indices:

```
df <- data.frame(
   predictions.2.2 = c(393.4, 511.41,  471.6, 679.1, 613.9, 456.1,  603.1, 668.1, 512.4),
   outsamp = c(662,  416, 594, 495, 442, 480, 263, 464, 507),
   me = c(268.5,  -95.4, 122.3, -184.1, -171.9,  23.8, -340.1, -204.1, -5.4 ),
   mae = c(268.5, 95.4, 122.3,  184.1, 171.9, 23.8, 340.1,  204.1, 5.4))

for(i in 1:nrow(df)){
   df[i,"me_rsum"] <- sum(df[i:(i+3),"me"])
   df[i,"outsamp_rsum"] <- sum(df[i:(i+3),"outsamp"])
}
df$percent_diff <- (df$me_rsum / df$outsamp_rsum) * 100
df
  predictions.2.2 outsamp     me   mae me_rsum outsamp_rsum percent_diff
1          393.40     662  268.5 268.5   111.3         2167     5.136133
2          511.41     416  -95.4  95.4  -329.1         1947   -16.902928
3          471.60     594  122.3 122.3  -209.9         2011   -10.437593
4          679.10     495 -184.1 184.1  -672.3         1680   -40.017857
5          613.90     442 -171.9 171.9  -692.3         1649   -41.983020
6          456.10     480   23.8  23.8  -525.8         1714   -30.676779
7          603.10     263 -340.1 340.1      NA           NA           NA
8          668.10     464 -204.1 204.1      NA           NA           NA
9          512.40     507   -5.4   5.4      NA           NA           NA
```

Or, vectorized:

```
sapply(1:nrow(df), function(i) sum(df[i:(i+3),"me"]) / sum(df[i:(i+3),"outsamp"]) * 100)
[1]   5.136133 -16.902928 -10.437593 -40.017857 -41.983020 -30.676779
[7]         NA         NA         NA
```

Comment: You're welcome. I'm glad to help. Good luck

Comment: In excitment I maybe got ahead of myself.... This solution copies row 4 in me, as the solution to me_rsum row 1. And then it systematically goes on like that.

Comment: Yes, sorry there's a typo. It should be `i:i+3` instead of `i+3`. I updated my answer. Sorry about that!

Comment: Hi @ChristofferNielsen-jasa, were you able to figure this out?

Comment: Hi @Skaqqs, sorry for the late answer. I had my first vacation in a year and a half, so it was work free. But back to business. Your update, now gives the same results as my own calculations in Excel. So yes, I got it to work and thank you once again.